# Subsection header overlaps with text in body

Tags: pdftex

So I have this text:

```
\subsection{ "Implementacja REST API z wykorzystaniem frameworka Django REST " -  Name Surname } 
 Pierwszy rozdział opisuje metodykę REST, jak i technolgie korzystające z niej. Przedstawione zostaną podstawowe definicje potrzebne do zrozumienia całości pracy. Opiszę paradygmaty jakie musi spełniać aplikacja by móc być nazwana RESTful. W dalszej części przedstawię technolgię Django, jak i framework Django REST i opiszę jak ten framework skorelowany jest z ideą REST.
```

But after compiling I get this
[image: Picture]

Is there a way to fit the header with text without shortening it ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Please post a complete code example, which contains the preamble, at least. Without knowing this, it's many times harder to tell, what's going on. It's complete, when a) we can copy, paste and compile your code, b) it still shows your problem. Thanks

Comment: You may increase the height of headline. With `geometry` package, this is controlled by option `headheight`.